# Testing if input or output is pending in a buffered stream

Tags: c, stdio

Is there a portable way to test in a C program whether some input or output is pending in a buffered stream such as `stdin` or `stdout`?

Comment: `kbhit()` does almost that, and it's almost portable :-D

Comment: @tevemadar: `kbhit()` does not do that: it tests whether some input is available from the terminal system handle. If the input has already been retrieved from the system, such as by `scanf()`, `kbhit()` would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  For `stdout`, you can keep track of this yourself by whether or not you've caused the buffer to be flushed.  For `stdin`, I think the closest thing is to check the file descriptor (though that may break portability) with `select`/`poll`.  Ultimately, a `FILE` is an opaque data type and only so much of it is exposed.

Comment: Checking the file descriptor will only query the kernel whether there is unread input. However, it won't query the input buffer of the C standard library (i.e. the buffer of the `FILE*`). Therefore, if, for example, the application reads 1 byte using `getchar()`, then the C standard library may read 7 bytes from the kernel (file descriptor) to the input buffer of the `FILE *`, and pass 1 byte to `getchar`. Now, querying the kernel's file descriptor may return that there is no further input, although there are still 6 unread bytes in the input buffer of the C standard library.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  That’s why I said it was the closest thing.